# unique ? about venting tankless water header

Tags: hvac, code-compliance, exhaust-vent, tankless

I am installing a tankless water heater at the house. My question is unique because I can not find a reference anywhere in the code and the installation manual about where to place my exhaust vent.

I am installing a tankless water heater in the basement. Due to reasons about where the basement floor drain is located and my HVAC duct work, it turns out my exhaust vent will most likely terminate outside next to the stairs for deck. I've attached a picture.

I meet all the requirements for distance from the window as well as the sliding glass door. Also, this vent does not go under the deck so that doesn't apply.

I'm going to install a Rheem flush mount [vent termination kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G2DL8LO) right where the stairs cross the rim joist. This picture shows my location.

[image]
I've talked with the building dept. in my town and they say just follow the manufactures instruction. Yet, those instructions don't cover my situation.

What is the general opinion about my setup? It seems acceptable to me, just not perfect.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm surprised the building inspector didn't object to this; I'm guessing there's something in the code that says "must be unobstructed for X feet ahead and Y feet on either side". That said, code questions are at least somewhat off-topic here.

Comment: As long as the vent is far enough away from building openings, I'm not aware of anything in the code that would prevent you from do this, as long as this is a direct-vent type water heater. If there's nothing in the manufacturer's documentation, then you're likely fine.  I might contact the manufacturer directly, and see what they have to say about it.